# Passing class from console application to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, parameter-passing

I'm newbie to WCF and I created a WCF service library and a console application project. I use Entity Framework (database-first) for connecting to the database in my WCF service library project. I want to send a class to the WCF service (my problem). In my WCF project I created a `ITest.cs` and `Test.cs` that like are below:

ITest.cs

```
[OperationContract]
bool GetData(role rr);
```

Test.cs

```
 public bool GetData(role rr)
    {
        try
        {
            iFlowEntities db = new iFlowEntities();
            db.roles.Add(rr);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
```

and I add this service reference to my console application project reference and I create my DB class model in console application  then use this service like :

```
        Role rr = new Role();
        rr.role1 = 10;
        rr.title = "sdsafas";
        TestClient client = new TestClient();
        bool re = client.GetData(rr); //This line has error
```

but in this  `bool re = client.GetData(rr);` I have this errors:

> Error 1
>   The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference3.TestClient.GetData(ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference3.role)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 2
>   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ConsoleApplication1.Role' to 'ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference3.role'

I googled but any example hasn't solution for my problem.

Comment: Is it possible for you to fully qualify TestClient to see if you get the same error i.e. TestClient should be MyNamepsoace.Class.TestClient??

Comment: I using it namespace ! like using system.servicereference;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use This **DataContract** in your entity model Class in **WCF Model** :

```
[DataContract]
Public Class role
{
[DataMember]
public int role1;
[DataMember]
public string title;
}
```

**But not use from client model.**

And use this parameter for **passing Class** Object to your WCF service **OerationContract** from your ConsoleApplicatione :

```
ServiceReference3.role role = new ServiceReference3.role();

role.role1=1;
role.title="Your Title";

TestClient client = new TestClient();
bool re = client.GetData(role);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data contract did not match with the service arguement.

`Error 2
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ConsoleApplication1.Role' to 'ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference3.role'`

Make it sure that you are using datacontract that came from your Service Reference and not the Role you created in your console. You should use data contract `ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference3.role` and not `ConsoleApplication1.Role` they are different.